# Collimating a cutting laser

Tags: optics, laser, lenses

I have a 450 nm, 5.5W laser from a cheap laser cutter. The beam focuses at about 20 mm away from the outlet rim of the laser unit's housing. I want to collimate the beam in order to be able to cut deeper objects. I am particularly interested in thick styrofoam, denser materials are, of course, difficult to cut due to limited laser power.

Now my understanding is that I have to place the current focal point of the laser in the focal plane of a collimating lens. The shorter the focal length of the collimator, the smaller the outgoing beam's diameter. But when the focal length of the collimator gets too short (and so the lens will be close to where the laser cuts by default), the incoming beam will have high intensity inside the lens and, hence, might damage the lens.

I have a box of scrap glass lenses, some coated, some not. Before blindly (well, hopefully not) trying them out, is there anything that can be concluded from the above parameters about when damage inside the glass might occur?

Comment: To reduce beam divergence you will have to increase beam diameter. Is that acceptable to you?

Comment: I think you might be better off by replacing the lens with one of a longer focal length. This would increase the working distance between the laser and piece being cut allowing you to still have a small spot and to make deeper cuts you can make multiple passes moving the piece being cut up. You will get a sharper cut.

Comment: If you want to go the two lens route you want the focal point of the second lense to be near the focal point of of the first lens. It depends but this keeps the focal point of the first lens out of the glass .  Be very careful about back reflections and eye safety. Ideally it wou be a good idea to use a finely threaded tube so you can adjust the focus. If you look at Thor labs or Newport under beam expanders you may get some ideas. Having fine adjustment control will matter.

Comment: @UVphoton:  "Be very careful about back reflections and eye safety." The cutter came with suitable safety glasses. Without them, even the diffuse scatterings are pretty bright, not dangerously so, but still deterring. And of course I will choose a matte base plate.